# Images for Gmaps pins - RoR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I have a gallery of images that correspond to pins on a map. I would like to have the pins be a small 32x32 thumbnails of those gallery images.

In my controller:

```
def index
  @arts = Art.all

  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@arts) do |art, marker|
  marker.lat art.latitude
  marker.lng art.longitude
  marker.infowindow art.artist
  marker.picture({
    url: :mural,
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
  })
end
```

you can see I tried to call `:mural` where you would normally have a URL to a single image. This just shows blank.

I've also tried w/ a variation that I call to get the images in the gallery `Art.mural.url(:thumb)` with no luck.

My map script in my index:

```
<div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    handler.getMap().setZoom(15);
  });
 </script>
```

using the [Gmaps4Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) gem

Comment: `:mural` is not a valid url so no surprise it fails. You simply have to pass a valid url

Comment: dont know your data structure but try: `art.mural.url(:thumb)`

Comment: gah! It was merely a caps on art, haha. Thanks!

Comment: also thanks for such a great gem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted as answer since it solves the problem.

Do:

```
art.mural.url(:thumb)
```

To pass a valid url